# got an error TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new BlobBuilder()')

Tags: jquery, safari

I'm using safari 5.1.7 version.

Actually we need to export the PPT file. we are getting a byte data from web services and convert byte to blob then export.

This is my piece of code

```
var BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder ||  window.MSBlobBuilder                                                                                        
 filedata -> byte data input                                                                                          var bb = new BlobBuilder();
    bb.append([new Uint8Array(filedata)]);
    var blob = bb.getBlob(contenttype);   
    window.location.assign(blob);
```

i got an error while executing in safari browser

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new
>   BlobBuilder()')

Comment: The `BlobBuilder` API has been deprecated, and shouldn't be used  anymore, you should be using the [**Blob contructor**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

Comment: It should also be noted that  `WebKitBlobBuilder` was never supported at all in Safari, only in previous versions of Chrome

Comment: adeneo - Is Blob contructor is supported for PPT file 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint' ? and safari 5.1 versions?

Comment: I have no idea, but looking at the support for [**BlobBuilder**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BlobBuilder) I can at least tell you that that isn't supported in Safari at all.

Comment: I have the same issue to save as doc file in safari 5.1.7. If any has the solution then share here.